# YTT overlays: modify arrays using data from that arrays

Tags: yaml, ytt

This question is about [YTT](https://carvel.dev/ytt/).
Is it possible to modify YAML list of items using the data from that items via overlays?

For example we have a template:

```
---
vlans:
- vlan-id: 10
- vlan-id: 20
- vlan-id: 30
some_other_configuration: #! some other config here
```

And using overlays we need to transform the template above into this:

```
---
vlans:
- vlan-id: 10
  vlan-name: vlan10
- vlan-id: 20
  vlan-name: vlan20
- vlan-id: 30
  vlan-name: vlan30
some_other_configuration: #! some other config here
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One can use an overlay *within* an overlay.

```yaml
#@ load("@ytt:overlay", "overlay")

#@ def with_name(vlan):
#@overlay/match missing_ok=True
vlan-name: #@ "vlan{}".format(vlan["vlan-id"])
#@ end

#@overlay/match by=overlay.all
---
vlans:
#@overlay/match by=lambda idx, left, right: "vlan-id" in left, expects="1+"
#@overlay/replace via=lambda left, right: overlay.apply(left, with_name(left))
-
```

which can be read:

- for all documents,
- in the `vlans:` map item...

  - for every array item it contains that has a map that includes the key "vland-id"...

    - replace the map with one that's been overlay'ed with the vlan name

https://carvel.dev/ytt/#gist:https://gist.github.com/pivotaljohn/33cbc52e808422e68c5ec1dc2ca38354

See also:

- the @overlay/replace action: https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/v0.40.0/lang-ref-ytt-overlay/#overlayreplace
- Overlays, programmatically: https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/v0.40.0/lang-ref-ytt-overlay/#programmatic-access.